# Code I have written for a happy number checker is not working, could someone check it over?

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

```
a = int(raw_input("Enter a number to check if it is happy:"))
l = map(int, str(a))
c = 0
while 1:
    for i in l:
       b = i
       c = c + b **2
    if c == 1:
        print "Happy Number!"
        raw_input("Hit enter to end")
        break
    elif c == a:
        print ("Not a Happy number")
        raw_input("Hit enter to end")
        break
    else:
        l = map(int, str(c))
```

This is the code I have written in Python, it works with the numbers 1 and 0, however any other number I have tried leaves it looping infinitely. Could somebody take a look and see what I have done wrong and suggest a solution? Thanks :)

For reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number

Comment: There are two problems with your code that I can see: first, because you set "c=0" *outside* the while loop, your `c` just keeps getting bigger and bigger.  Second, because you're only comparing to the original "a" to break, then if there was a pattern which went "x -> y -> z -> y -> z -> y -> z.." you'd never spot it.  I'm too lazy to figure out whether that could happen, but if you keep track of the numbers you've seen so far like several people have suggested and check if you've seen c yet, that should work.

Comment: @Ricochet_Bunny, now there is even a programming example in wikipedia...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = int(raw_input("Enter a number to check if it is happy: "))
visited = set()
while 1:
    if a == 1:
        print "Number is happy!"
        break
    a = sum(int(c) ** 2 for c in str(a))
    if a in visited:
        print "Number is sad!"
        break
    visited.add(a)
```

Comment: Yeah this seems to make a lot more sense
Could you briefly explain the difference between a set and a list? I didn't understand the explanation on the python docs

Comment: A set cannot have duplicate elements, but a list can. If you add 2 to the set {1, 2, 3}, the result will still be {1, 2, 3}. But if you add 2 to the list [1, 2, 3], the result will be [1, 2, 3, 2]. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain that, I appreciate it, it did help!

Answer (score 3):

You should keep all the values generated during the process:

```
def is_happy_number(n):
     seen = set()
     while True:
           digits = [int(c) for c in str(n)]
           n = sum(digit**2 for digit in digits)
           if n == 1:
                return True
           elif n in seen:
                return False
           seen.add(n)

>>> is_happy_number(1)
True
>>> is_happy_number(7)
True
>>> is_happy_number(11)
False
```

That's because if you have a loop it does not mean that the loop will start where you started.
For example:

```
11 -> 2
2 -> 4
4 -> 16
16 -> 37
37 -> 58
58 -> 89
89 -> 145
145 -> 42
42 -> 20
20 -> 4
```

As you can see you begin with "11" but the loop starts with "4".

Comment: There's a bug: you're always computing the digits of `n`, not `res`.

Comment: this code is also wrong ... I just ran it on all the numbers from wikipedia ... 1 True
7 False
10 True
13 False
19 False
23 False
28 False
31 False
 it should return true for all of them...

Comment: @Oz123 I've just double checked and it _does_ return `True` for all numbers in `{1, 7, 10, 13, 19, 23, 28, 31}`. Maybe you used the old version?
Anyway I think this is quite a clear translation of the definition: sum the squares of the digits(`sum(digit**2 for digit in digits)`) if it's one return `True`, if it was already seen return False.
You could improve it slightly adding "n" to the set at the beginning, this would save one iteration in some cases.

Comment: Yes I understand now about the loop staring with a number different to the original, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put a print statement inside the while loop

```
while 1:
    print(l)
```

and see what is happening when the user inputs, say `2`.

You need to reset `c = 0`:

```
else:
    l = map(int, str(c))
    c = 0
```

and the condition for an unhappy number needs to change too. Once you put in the debugging print statement, I think you'll see what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems, you need to reset "c", and it almost never loops back on itself. Try this:

```
a = int(raw_input("Enter a number to check if it is happy:"))
l = map(int, str(a))
while 1:
    c = 0
    for i in l:
       b = i
       c = c + b **2
    if c == 1:
        print "Happy Number!"
        raw_input("Hit enter to end")
        break
    elif c == 4:
        print ("Not a Happy number")
        raw_input("Hit enter to end")
        break
    else:
        l = map(int, str(c))
```

I moved the "c = 0" command and adjusted the elif statment

Answer (score 0):

Why if elif c == a: ? 
Wiki : "If n is not happy, then its sequence does not go to 1. What happens instead is that it ends up in the cycle"

Try this:

```
r=int(raw_input("Enter Number :"))
happy=[]
for _ in range(r):
    number=_
    l=[]
    s=0
    while not (s in l[:-1]) and s!=1:
        s=0
        for __ in str(number):
            s+= int(__)**2
        l.append(s)
        number=s
    if l[-1]==1:

        happy.append(_)

print ("Happy Numbers are :")
print happy
```

Comment: I'm genuinely puzzled now.  This is two answers you've given in the last half hour both of which give underscore names to loop variables that you go on to use.  Are you under the impression that Python only allows loop variable names to be composed of underscores?

Comment: No I'm not. I prefer underscores over 'x','y', 'temp', 'each', etc.

Comment: Apparently you don't, though.  You write `number=_` on the next line.  Readability counts.

Answer (score 0):

```
number=int(input("enter how many happy number to print"))
count=0
print("the first {} happy numbers are:".format(number))
for i in range(1,100000):#you can change the range if you want more happy numbers
    n=i
    while n!=1 and count!=number:
        num=n
        temp=0
        while num!=0:
            rem=num%10
            temp=temp+(rem**2)
            num=num//10
        n=temp
        if n==4:#condition to break the loop if it is no a happy number
            break    
    if n==1:
        count=count+1  
        print (i)
```

Comment: Explaining what exactly you have fixed would be helpful